# How to run windows command using ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. :)

I am trying to run windows command (mkdir, cd..) using ruby script. I know this will be very simple using shell scripting. But I want to try doing it with ruby, is there a way I can do it?

eg.

1. mkdir foldername
2. ssh node name
3. cd..
4. rm filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the stdlib [`FileUtils`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html).

Just require this **lib** by using the line `require 'fileutils'`, and get access to all the methods of this lib and use those as per your need.

`mkdir foldername` can be written as :

```
FileUtils.mkdir foldername
```

`cd..` can be written as :

```
FileUtils.cd('..')
```

`rm filename` can be written as :

```
FileUtils.rm filename
```

Install the gem [`net-ssh`](http://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v1/chapter-1.html) to do such operations `ssh node name`.